# Build error and fatal exception using Jsoup

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, jsoup

I want to use jsoup so I downloaded the jsoup-1.9.2.jar file and moved it in my libs folder in Android Studio. When I tried to build the project I get the following error:

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformResourcesWithMergeJavaResForDebug'.
```

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: com.android.builder.packaging.DuplicateFileException: Duplicate files copied in APK META-INF/maven/org.jsoup/jsoup/pom.xml
>       File1: /Users/David/AndroidStudioProjects/Vertretungsplan2/app/libs/jsoup-1.9.2.jar
>       File2: /Users/David/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.jsoup/jsoup/1.9.2/5e3bda828a80c7a21dfbe2308d1755759c2fd7b4/jsoup-1.9.2.jar

I tried several things suggested all around Google. I excluded these files in the build.gradle:

```
exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-full.xml'
exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-full.properties'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.jsoup/jsoup/pom.xml'
exclude 'META-INF/maven/org.jsoup/jsoup/pom.properties'
exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.properties'
exclude 'org/jsoup/nodes/entities-base.xml'
```

This let Android Studio build the project successfully but whenever I try to use jsoup I get the following error:

```
08-14 18:52:53.852 8200-8906/de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: IntentService[RefreshService]
                                                                                    Process: de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan, PID: 8200
                                                                                    java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.access$000(Entities.java:17)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Entities.java:20)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Document.java:371)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Document.java:18)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:29)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:42)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:52)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:136)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:653)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:217)
                                                                                        at de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan.RefreshService.doStuff(RefreshService.java:252)
                                                                                        at de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan.RefreshService.onHandleIntent(RefreshService.java:93)
                                                                                        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66)
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
                                                                                     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null
                                                                                        at java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:246)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.loadEntities(Entities.java:241)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.<clinit>(Entities.java:225)
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities.access$000(Entities.java:17) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Entities$EscapeMode.<clinit>(Entities.java:20) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document$OutputSettings.<init>(Document.java:371) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.nodes.Document.<init>(Document.java:18) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.initialiseParse(TreeBuilder.java:29) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.TreeBuilder.parse(TreeBuilder.java:42) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.HtmlTreeBuilder.parse(HtmlTreeBuilder.java:52) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.parser.Parser.parseInput(Parser.java:30) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.helper.DataUtil.parseByteData(DataUtil.java:136) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.parse(HttpConnection.java:653) 
                                                                                        at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:217) 
                                                                                        at de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan.RefreshService.doStuff(RefreshService.java:252) 
                                                                                        at de.gymnasium_beetzendorf.vertretungsplan.RefreshService.onHandleIntent(RefreshService.java:93) 
                                                                                        at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:66) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                                                        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148) 
                                                                                        at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
```

I have no idea what I have to do to solve this so any help is appreciated. If my post is missing any information you guys need just let me know. Thanks!

Java code that uses jsoup:

```
public void doStuff () {
    String url = "http://gymnasium-beetzendorf.de/uorganisation/vplan.html";

    try {
        Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();

        Elements div = document.select("div.content");
        Elements a = div.select("a");

        Log.i(MainActivity.TAG, "anzahl der links " + String.valueOf(a.size()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: It'd be useful to actually see your JSoup code. The error says `Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: in == null`, which I assume is an InputStream?

Comment: And you probably could have used a Maven dependency rather than a JAR file to avoid the first error

Comment: I edited the code above. From what I've read the npe is not my fault but because of the exclude statements I put in the build.gradle.

Comment: Right, and that's the reason your code crashes as well. Based on just the content of the error, I think the `entities` files are needed. Your first error only said the `pom.xml` was duplicated

Comment: Have you tried `compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'` instead of a JAR file, and no exclusions?

Comment: That's been my compile statement the whole time: compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
I tried removing the exclude statements one by one but didn't solve anything. It then leaves me with the build error.

Comment: Then remove the JAR file. You need one or the other, not both. Preferably that compile statement

Comment: Okay now I feel stupid. Removed the jar file and excludes and now it's working. I thought I needed the jar file in my project. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome ;) Gradle will download the JAR files for you.

Comment: Yeah I guess that makes sense since I do the same thing with the Android support library. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Gradle error is stating there are duplicate files that are conflicting between the JAR file, and the compiled Gradle dependency, which you probably have this in your dependencies.

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
```

Therefore, you shouldn't need to download a JAR file, or exclude anything, you can simply use that library.